# client.change_presence syntaxe error

Tags: python, discord.py

Need your help.
I'm trying to make a self bot that display the music I listen in personal statut, but I've got a syntax error with client.change_presence, and I don't understand why. Cna you help me ?

```
import discord, asyncio, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

client = discord.Client()

@asyncio.coroutine
def main_task():
    yield from client.login('token')
    yield from client.connect()
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Paper Please'))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main_task())
except:
    loop.run_until_complete(client.logout())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `await` doesn't exist in all of them.

Comment: Hoo.... Yeah... Was looking in the doc, and that how they use it. Juste erase await, and no more error. Thanks bro.

Comment: Hmm. Deleting `await` will get rid of the Syntax Error, but I expect it was there for a reason in the first place. It is likely that the function will not behave correctly down the line. The real solution is to upgrade to a version of Python that supports `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python script use the [`await` expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) and this expression was introduced in Python 3.5 .

From [What’s New In Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html):

> New syntax features:
>
> [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492), coroutines with async and await syntax.

You have to upgrade your Python interpreter to Python 3.5 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using Python 3.4.

From here, you have 2 options. Either install Python 3.5 or 3.6 and continue using `async`/`await`, or convert your code to use the Python 3.4 syntax

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def main_task():
    ...
    yield from client.change_presence(...)
```